# Convert NSNumbers into NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsnumber

In the code below, I have a dictionary of NSNumbers that are turned into an Array.  It is then randomly sorted and the first four rows need to be displayed in the appropriate labels. NSLog does show that the array displays the appropriate numbers.  I believe the code fails because I need to convert the NSNumbers into NSStrings.  What is the applicable code or what am I overlooking?

```
-(IBAction)shakeit {
NSDictionary * myExampleDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"dictionaryKey"];
exampleArray = [myExampleDict allValues];
NSUInteger count = [exampleArray count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
   int nElements = count - i;
   int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
   [exampleArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}
NSString *one = [exampleArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *two = [exampleArray objectAtIndex:2];
NSString *three = [exampleArray objectAtIndex:3];
NSString *four = [exampleArray objectAtIndex:4];
select1.text = one;
select2.text = two;
select3.text = three;
select4.text = four;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert NSNumber to NSString and use it in other View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969972/convert-nsnumber-to-nsstring-and-use-it-in-other-view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I believe the code fails because I
>   need to convert the NSNumbers into
>   NSStrings.

you are right, try the following:

```
NSString *one   = [[exampleArray objectAtIndex:1] stringValue];
NSString *two   = [[exampleArray objectAtIndex:2] stringValue];
NSString *three = [[exampleArray objectAtIndex:3] stringValue];
NSString *four  = [[exampleArray objectAtIndex:4] stringValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you need to convert it to `NSString`.

You simply need to call `stringValue`, a method of `NSNumber`. Like :

```
select1.text = [one stringValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied answer from this link
[How to convert NSNumber to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969972/convert-nsnumber-to-nsstring-and-use-it-in-other-view)

```
NSString *myString = [NSNumber stringValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
blank = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[nsnumber_var integerValue]];
```