# Send NSNumber to UILabel in another view

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, uilabel, nsnumber

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert NSNumber to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969972/how-to-convert-nsnumber-to-nsstring)

Segue to pass string from MainViewController to DetailViewController:

MainViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DetailSegue"]) {

        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

//Name:
detailViewController.detailName = [[sortedObjects objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];

//Attempt with number:
detailViewController.detailPopularity = [[sortedObjects objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row] valueForKey:@"Popularity"];
    }
}
```

DetailViewController.h

```
//Name:
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *detailName;

//Attempt with number:
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *popularityLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *detailPopularity;
```

DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

//Name:    
nameLabel.text = detailName;

//Attempt with number:
popularityLabel.text = detailPopularity;
}
```

In this example the app crashes because it can't display a NSNumber in UILabel. I need to see an example on how to convert the NSNumber into a NSString so I can display it in a label, I've tried in different ways but I can't find the right combination to fix the error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see your NSNumber part, but this should work:

```
Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[YourNSNumber doubleValue]];
```

You can change doubleValue to whatever you need, could be intValue and so on. And you need to do a bit research to see what kind of format of the string you want when you convert a floating point to a string.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

in addition to existing answers you can use without any other classes

```
Label.text = [theNumber stringValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSStringWithFormat`.

```
popularityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", theNumber];
```

If you want a specific format you can use:

```
popularityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%.2f", [theNumber doubleValue]];
```