# How do I place an __NSCFNumber in an NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber

I have an `NSNumber` variable called `task_id`. I want to place that `NSNumber` variable in an `NSString` (post request). Here is what I have tried:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&task_id=%@", task_id];
```

and:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&task_id=%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",task_id]];
```

For some reason the string doesn't include the task_id value to the POST request. How can I place the `NSNumber` into the string?

**Update**

task_id is an NSCFNumber according to this code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [task_id class]);
```

Many thanks indeed,

Peter

Comment: what error are you receiving?

Comment: What do you get for `post`?

Comment: I get an empty response, which is expected. When I place a number in the string (hard-coded) I get the appropiate response. I get no objective-c errors

Comment: it doesn't matter whether its NSNumber or NSCFNumber.check this link for differences http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357063/what-is-the-class-nscfnumber-in-ios-4-1.

Comment: @PeterStuart: I did not ask for the response. If you want help to find the actual problem, then show the NSLog output of `task_id` and `post`, and also the code how you sent the request.

Comment: Okay, sorry I misread your question, when I call post in NSLog I get "&task_id=XXX". Maybe the problem lies somewhere else then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyones efforts. It turns out that wasn't the problem, and the problems lies within the web server!

I misunderstood the whole thing,

Thanks guys,

Peter

Answer (score 11):

```
NSNumber *myNumber = @12;
NSString *myString = [myNumber stringValue];
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&task_id=%@", myString];
```

It was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3969998/2458651)

Comment: I already tried that answer.

Comment: Why should that work better than the original code? Btw. `[NSNumber stringValue]` does not compile.

Comment: Where he said `NSNumber`, it is assumed that you would put in your variable for your `NSNumber` object.

Answer (score 2):

it should work.But anyway, if `task-id is just an int` ,

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&task_id=%d", task_id.intValue];
```

Comment: Why should that work better than the original code?

Comment: well i said, it should work for obvious reasons. But this kinda plan B.

Comment: "It should work" is a useful *comment*. I can see no reason why "Plan B" should work better ...

Comment: @MartinR care to explain "betterness"? pls . iam a leaner.

Comment: What I meant is: If `NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&task_id=%d", task_id.intValue];` works then the original code would work as well. There is no reason to replace the original code with the one that you suggested.